# Eclipse and a project example question

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jpa, export

I've been working on the following example:
http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html

I'm getting lost at the creation of .JAR file and then creating a .WAR file.

Do I start off with a new JPA Project and add the 3 source files? Then I export into a .JAR and import that into a new project?

Answer (score 0):

I've not done the tutuorial myself, but I assume that it is asking you to export the project you created in parts 2 and 3 as a JAR file first.  Then create a new project with the code and web.xml from part 4.  Then copy the JAR you exported into the WEB-INF/lib folder of your new project.  Then export the new project as a WAR file.

The resulting WAR should then have the structure listed under the packaging/deployment section.